# How to get button events in device sleep mode?

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to get volume up and down button long press event when the device is in sleep mode? If so, then how is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it by creating service, that will listen to long press, but would it work or not depends on power management policy on every specific device.